# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when using multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

When I use one ajax method (to get json from php file) it works well. But i must insert into that php file a variable with mac address. I tried to do it by one function, but it won't work. I tried it like that code above, but it didn't work either. I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" from Opera javascript debugger (DragonFly). Anyone can help me out?

```
function ajaxInsertMac(mac){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "js/ajax_db_credits.php",
        data: "mac=" + mac,
        success: function(){
        alert("executed insert");
        }


    });
}

function ajaxExtractCredits(handleData){ 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'js/ajax_db_credits.php',
    async:false,
    success: function(result) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
        handleData(jsonData);
        }
    });
}




var bucket = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function order(bucket){
//var mac = stb.GetDeviceMacAddress();
var mac = "00:00";
ajaxInsertMac(mac);
ajaxExtractCredits(function(jsonData){
var operator = jsonData[0].operator;
var mail = jsonData[0].mail;
alert(mail);
 });

}

order(bucket);
```

Comment: You're returning HTML, which starts with a `<`, and that's not JSON, so `JSON.parse` is failing, and that error is thrown

Comment: @adeneo But when i delete ajaxInsertMac and set mac in php file manually it works and extracts json. So...

Comment: I'm just telling you what the error is, you should log the `result` in the console and see what you're getting.

Comment: I found answer: `function order(bucket){
//var mac = stb.GetDeviceMacAddress();
var mac = "00:00";

var result = $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
        url: "js/ajax_db_credits.php",
        data: { mac : mac },
  async: false,
  success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
  return result;
  }
 }).responseText;
 

console.log(result);
var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
var mail = jsonData[0].mail;
alert(mail); 


}

order(bucket);` Thank you mate! :)